# erb code is not working in javascript <script> tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have Post table with title and content attributes. I want to make auto complete textfield where user are suggested by Post title. I am trying to add [jquery auto-complete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in my rails application. I am doing like this ..

controller (Adding Posts title in Array)--

```
  @posttitle = []
  Post.all.each do |g|
    @posttitle << g.title 
  end
```

View --

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Search Religious Places...", :id=>"tags" %>

 <script>
   $(function() {
   var availableTags = <%= @posttitle %>;
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
   });
   });
 </script>
```

But its not showing any suggestion (auto-complete is not working). I don't know whats going wrong. Please help

Comment: I think you should not use the ruby array in javascript. It will not evaluated as an array.

Comment: @ManojMonga I think you are right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<script>
   var availableTags = <%= raw @posttitle %>;
   $(function() {

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
         source: availableTags
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution once again but still not working :(

Comment: `@posttitle` is a Array if I put like this `<%= @posttitle %>` in my html then it will show array like this `["xyz", "wxt", "etc"]`

Comment: Can you try to edit first line to say
 $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Problem is not `$(document).ready(function() {` this. When I put hard coded value like `var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];` then it works fine...

Comment: hats off dude, you just save my life :) Thank you so much :) Its working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31619/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-ermin-dedovic)

Comment: @ErminDedovic What do you do if it's a string separated by spaces?

Comment: @andy4thehuynh You can split the string by space and you get the same array as shown above.

Comment: For those of you who cannot get it working, you probably have leaked the string into your script without double quotes. You should try: `var availableTags = "<%= raw @posttitle %>";`

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of items in Ruby to appear as a javascript array, you'll need to:

1) get it into a comma separated list of values
2) wrap each value in quotes
3) escape the value so that quotes do not cause javascript errors

If you want just the title:

controller:

```
@titles = Post.pluck(:title)
```

and then in your view:

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
     var availableTags = [<%= @titles.map{|title| escape_javascript(title)}.join(", ") %>];
     $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Line `@titles = Post.all.pluck(:title)` should be `@titles = Post.pluck(:title)`. I tried from this way, not working

Comment: auto-complete function is not working. Its not showing any suggestion. Well I tried to do like this `<script>
   $(function() {
    var availableTags = [<%= @titles.map{|title| escape_javascript(title)}.join(", ") %>];
     $('#tags').focus(function() {
           alert('hi');
      });
   });
 </script>` for testing purpose but alert box is not showing means line 1 is not executed correctly...

Comment: I don't think this needs its own answer, and maybe this wasn't possible when written, but another way to do this would be to use to_json so:
`var availableTags = <%= @titles.map(&:title).to_json.html_safe %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use the ruby array in javascript. It will not evaluated as an array. Instead you can create the javascript array and use it as

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = new Array();
    <% @posttitle.each do |post| %>
      availableTags.push(<%= post %>);
    <% end %>
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to put like this `<script>
   $(function() {  
    var availableTags = new Array();  
    <% @posttitle.each do |post| %>  
      availableTags.push(<%= post %>);
    <% end %>
     $('#tags').focus(function() {
           alert('hi');
      });
   });
 </script>` but alert box is not showing. It means `var availableTags...` that line having error